# How does medium.com (for example) generate the URL fragment hash?

Tags: website, javascript, tracking

Has anyone identified the scripts or techniques used by medium.com (or other popular site) to generate what appears to be a unique hash value after the URL fragment?

Contrived example: `#.lfr25xei4`

They change with every page refresh (at least in my experience).

(I considered asking this on Stack Overflow but not sure it belongs there.)

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a few months since this question was posted, but I got interested in the same thing and here are my findings.

The hash is generated client-side, in Javascript, and it's based on current timestamp. The code looks like this:

```
hash = generateHash().substr(0, 9)

generateHash = function() {
  return Math.floor(2147483648 * Math.random()).toString(36) + 
    Math.abs(Math.floor(2147483648 * Math.random()) ^ (0, getTimestamp)()).toString(36)
}

getTimestamp = Date.now || function() {
  return +new Date
}
```

(functions have been renamed for clarity)

Comment: What's the point of the random hash?  I find it really annoying.  I can't tell if I've already bookmarked a page, unless I replace the hash with something consistent, like `#nada`.  Since it's a URL fragment the server never sees it, so it must be used in XHR API calls .  I assumed it was for referrer tracking but that makes no sense either...

Comment: It is annoying, and I cut the anchors out, too.

The server does see it, because the JS sends it in some Ajax requests. I found it in e.g. `https://medium.com/_/batch`, so I am more than sure that is is used for tracking who shared which URL and this way they can make out a tree of referrals.

So, if that answers your original question, please accept the answer. Thanks.